# Metamaterial/Optics Book Recommendation

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, metamaterials

I recently won a prize at my school for physics (£25) for which they ask that we spend some money they have given us on a book with which they can present us during an assembly. Given that over the past two years I have dedicated a lot of work to learning about the fields of metamaterials and optics, I'd quite like to get a book which reflects the fact to some extent. However, there are a few possible categories I would think which might do this:

**Seminal Work**

I was considering trying to buying Physical Review Letters Volume 85, Issue 18
30 October 2000, based off of the letter contained within by John Pendry on the topic of a perfect lens (given that, as my name suggests, I'm very interested in the topic of doubly negative metamaterials, I thought this might be a perfect book). But my knowledge of what works were the most influential is limited both by a lack of personal knowledge, and by what happens to spring to mind, so what important works would people suggest I might buy on the topic of metamaterials (preferably of the optical variety).

**Textbook Style Book**

Another direction is to buy something which is more utilitarian in nature than some seminal work, perhaps a textbook on optics of some sort. However, given the general availability of most non-specialised information on the internet, I'd ideally like a textbook which I'd be able to keep and use as a reference text on optics for a while to come. It doesn't have to be something I'd completely understand at the moment, but something which would be comprehensible to me after studying physics at uni, and which I could chip away at before then. I know I've seen books before going into lots of detail on quite niche topics of research, so perhaps something somewhere between a book to that professional level of detail which may not be useful if I never come into that field, and a book which is too general to be that in depth in any topic. So any suggestions here, too, would be very helpful!

**Anything else**

If there's any other book that you think a physicist interested in optics and metamaterials would enjoy, I'd appreciate knowing that, too!

Thank you very much for all your times, and all your recommendations will be appreciated!

Comment: The Phys. Rev. Lett. issue would be a waste of money - it's a journal issue, and it's extremely unlikely to contain any other papers on the same subject. The only reasons to buy such issues in hard copy nowadays are sentimental. Get a PDF of the paper itself and move on. (If you're having a hard time finding a PDF, just email the author directly. Heck, you could use the opportunity to ask for book recommendations.)

Comment: A textbook on optical metamaterials is a much better option, but I'm sorry to say that £25 is going to fall rather short, by a factor of two or three, for most works in this category. I'd recommend looking through the Dover catalogue if that's your price range. (They specialize in bringing old out-of-print books, which are still current and relevant, back to life, at very low prices.)

Comment: Is this some kind of endowment to the school (e.g. a book for the library), or is this a prize for your personal collection? If it's the latter what level of education is this?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Emilio. I did wonder if most of the textbooks would be outside of my price range, so I might supplement it with some of my own money. And, Novice C, it's for my own personal use. I'm currently a year before university, but I have spent the past two years working intensively on metamaterials, and so I'm personally at the standard where I can roughly follow most metamaterials research papers I've found, although as I'm self-taught, I sometimes have difficulty finding out precisely about new terms/concepts when they crop up - hence I thought about a textbook.

Comment: Wow, the optics section of Dover Publications looks exactly what I was looking for!